# Python creating a smaller sub-array from a larger 2D NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

So I have a large NumPy array that takes the following form:

```
data = [[2456447.64798471, 4, 15.717, 0.007, 5, 17.308, 0.019, 6, 13.965, 0.006],
        [2456447.6482855, 4, 15.768, 0.018, 5, 17.347, 0.024, 6, 14.001, 0.023],
        [2456447.648575, 4, 15.824, 0.02, 5, 17.383, 0.024, 6, 14.055, 0.023]]
```

I want to create a sub array that looks like this:

```
[[4, 15.717, 5, 17.308, 6, 13.965], 
 [4, 15.768, 5, 17.347, 6, 14.001],
 [4, 15.824, 5, 17.383, 6, 14.055]]
```

Basically I want to select out the first column, and then starting at the 4th column I want to select out every 3rd column. I tried to figure this out how to approach this with something like `data[1:6:?]` but I didn't understand how to step through and only get the columns that I wanted.

Also I need this to be scalable for an array that extends horizontally. So I don't just want to hard code the column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick, it scales horizontally and vertically and it's easy and works.

```
subArray = []
newRow = []
for row in data:
    for i in xrange(0,len(row)):
        if (i % 3 == 0):
            continue
        newRow.append(row[i])
    subArray.append(newRow)
    newRow = []
```

Comment: if you need this to be scalable and not statically sized let me knkow and I can change the code

Comment: Yeah I was trying to make something scalable because my actual data array is much longer both horizontally and vertically. If you have a scalable solution that would be awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I ran your code and I got the following error: `if (row.index(element) % 3 == 0):
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin that's because your data is actually a numpy array, try my new code

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin If you are using python 3.x you should take the x off of xrange btw

Answer (score 7):

You could do this:

```
>>> data[:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]]
array([[  4.   ,  15.717,   5.   ,  17.308,   6.   ,  13.965],
       [  4.   ,  15.768,   5.   ,  17.347,   6.   ,  14.001],
       [  4.   ,  15.824,   5.   ,  17.383,   6.   ,  14.055]])
```

Comment: what is going on here, slice notation with a list? and why is there a comma after the colon?

Comment: @Stephan, since `data` is a NumPy array, it can be accessed with integer indexing. The list can be another array too. [The docs for it are here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer). The comma separates slicing along the axes. So `data[1:2, :]` would select the first row and all the columns, while `data[:, 1:2]` would select all the rows and the first column.

Comment: are you sure `data[1:2]` doesn't get the second item?  I thought slice was 0 indexed so `data[0:1]` would get the first item

Comment: First as in directly after zeroth. I was following the notation in the original question. Sorry I wasn't clear.